# AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider CancellationTokenSource has been disposed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-keyvault, .net-6.0

I'm currently using `IConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());` to add Azure Key Vault secrets into my dotnet 6 application.

Whenever I resolve an instance of `var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();` I get a version of IConfiguration that I can use to access all keys across providers.

```
    public static T GetOptions<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string sectionName)
    where T : new()
    {
        using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
        var options = new T();
        section.Bind(options);

        return options;
    }
```

But when I leave the above method, the instance of IConfiguration apparently gets disposed and I receive the following exception:

> at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException(ExceptionResource
> resource)    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()
> at
> Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Dispose(Boolean
> disposing)    at
> Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Dispose()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.DisposeRegistrationsAndProvidersUnsynchronized()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Dispose()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Dispose()

I assume that IConfiguration is a singleton in the IServiceCollection, but why is getting disposed then. And why is the CancellationTokenSource NULL when disposing the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but why is getting disposed then

You are building and disposing the whole service provider which leads to disposing everything (what implements `IDisposable`) created/owned by it:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<MyDisposable>(); 
// note that changing to services.AddSingleton(new MyDisposable()); will change behaviour of the program
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var myDisposable = sp.GetRequiredService<MyDisposable>();
sp.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine(myDisposable.Disposed); // prints True

public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public bool Disposed { get; set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

In general you should avoid building `ServiceProvider` multiple times and should use existing APIs to get configuration where needed. But without rest of the code it is hard to tell how `GetOptions` should be changed/refactoried.

Comment: @Bjorn, did you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @PepitoFernandez I doubt that author of the post will see your comment. As for solving the issue - it should be straightforward - do not build whole service provider. In the worst case - build the configuration but better use DI and/or exposed configuration properties. It is hard to suggest concrete solution without seeing the real code.

Comment: My issue was too many nested callbacks. When I moved up (out instead) of the inner callback, it all worked as expected.